# How to deal with empty JSON file

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a problem with returning data for an empty JSON. If there is data for a given user, everything works fine, unfortunately with empty JSON `[]` the data disappears and the `else` condition does not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
const Header = (): ReactElement => {
    const url = '/api/header';

    const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((json) => setData(json.data));
    }, []);

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="xs" justify-content="center">
            {data.map((collection) => {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    return (
                        <Header>
          
                            data1: {collection['data1']}
                            <br />
                            data2: {collection['data2']}
                            <br />
                            data3: {collection['data3']}
                            <br />
                        </Header>
                    );
                } else
                    return (
                        <Header>
                            {' '}
                            data4: 0 <br /> data5: 0
                        </Header>
                    );
            })}
        </Container>
    );
};
```

I'd like to return this:

```
                    return (
                        <StatisticsHeader>
                            {' '}
                            data4: 0 <br /> data5: 0
                        </Header>
                    );
```

in case of an empty JSON

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking `data.length` inside `data.map` method. Since data is empty, `data.map` never renders anything, along with your condition.

Proper code would look like this:

```
const Header = (): ReactElement => {
  const url = '/api/header';

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((json) => setData(json.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xs" justify-content="center">
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        data.map((collection) => (
          <Header>
            data1: {collection.data1}
            <br />
            data2: {collection.data2}
            <br />
            data3: {collection.data3}
            <br />
          </Header>
        ))
      ) : (
        <Header>
          {' '}
          data4: 0 <br /> data5: 0
        </Header>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

`data.length > 0 ? ... : ...` is a shorthand way of doing `if (data.length > 0) { ... } else { ... }` called the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Some other useful tips:

1. You can move the `const url = 'api/header';` outside your component, like this:

```
    const url = '/api/header';
    const Header = (): ReactElement => {
    ...
```

That way the URL constant won't re-render unnecessarily since it is static.

2. When using typescript, refer to using `React.FC`:

Instead of:

```
const Header = (): ReactElement =>
```

Use:

```
const Header: React.FC = () =>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
return (
    <Container maxWidth="xs" justify-content="center">
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        data.map((collection) => (
          <Header>
            data1: {collection.data1}
            <br />
            data2: {collection.data2}
            <br />
            data3: {collection.data3}
            <br />
          </Header>
        ))
      ) : (
        <Header>
          {' '}
          data4: 0 <br /> data5: 0
        </Header>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
```